# Parsing a json string as a comma separated values

Tags: android

I am parsing a **JSON array** as follows,
Following is part of my json...

```
[
  "GetStatutoryMappingsSuccess",
  {
    "statutory_mappings": {
      "9": {
        "compliance_names": [
          {
            "url": null,
            "compliance_name": "Compliance Task 2603161715-1"
          },
          {
            "url": null,
            "compliance_name": "Compliance Task 2603161715-2"
          }
        ]
      },
      "10": {
        "compliance_names": [
          {
            "url": null,
            "compliance_name": "Compliance Task 2603161717-1"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]

for (int i = 0; i < compliances.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject compliancesJSONObject = compliances.getJSONObject(i);

    complianceTask = compliancesJSONObject.getString("compliance_task");

}
```

The problem is that, when the loop reaches the  `index 0` it might contain **two** compliance tasks and when the loop reaches `index 1`, it contains **one** compliance tasks. What I wish to do is that, when there are multiple compliance tasks in  a specific index, I wish to **concat** them as comma separated compliance tasks. How can I do so?

Comment: Do you mean to say, that count of compliance tasks may vary for every index of loop? And there is no key as `"compliance_task"` in your json?

Comment: There is no key named as "compliance_task" in your JSON Data.

Comment: i mean compliance name